# Shrinkwrap Modifier - Can't select Vertex Group

Tags: modifiers, vertex-groups, shrinkwrap

I created a vertex group to project an object on via the shrinkwrap modifier. But I can't select any vertex groups in the drop-down.

Any ideas anyone? Thank you very much for taking a look!

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You are supposed to create a vertex group on the object which hosts the modifier, not the target object. You currently can't set a target vertex group with the shrinkwrap modifier.

The vertices will be projected against all of the target object's geometry.

[image]

Comment: Oh, Alright! Got it, thanks for the clarification. Thank you for the explanatory animation, very helpful!