# How to use bezier curve in shrinkwrap modifier with vertex groups?

Tags: modifiers, bezier-curves, vertex-groups, shrinkwrap

I'm trying to make neck part of sweater:
[image]

and I thought that I can do it like that:

1. create bezier curve
2. make vertex group for neck part of sweater
3. add shrinkwrap modifier to curve with selected vertex group
4. done

But I don't have any vertex group in modifier:

[image]

[image]

I've tried to make things like in this [question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/175607/shrinkwrap-modifier-cant-select-vertex-group), but I just can't select curve as object in shrinkwrap modifier. How to fix that? Or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: The vertex group in the Shrinkwrap modifier is supposed to be the vertices in the object that are going to be shrinkwrapped onto the target, plus I think there are not vertex groups in curves, so you're probably making some confusions here?

Comment: Could you duplicate that group of vertices, instead, convert to a curve, and use the curve for subsequent steps?